# How do I dynamically check and set an instances variable values?

Tags: python, dynamic

I want to be able to dynamically check and set an instances attribute values. The use-case is for a point-like class, where I want to have a custom 'set_value' method that checks for which value the client is trying to set, and then determines what to do from there.

My goal is to have a method which allows the values (x, y) of the instance to be set once, and then disallows future assignments to those variables... effectively making them 'immutable'.
I know that this does not technically make them immutable, I'm relying on the gentleman's agreement to not do funny stuff and mess around with it.

I've trying messing around with the **setattr** method, to no avail, as it then won't allow the init to run in the first place.

My class is shown below:

```
class Node:
    """Represents the nodes as points with a position x, y."""

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, x_state=0, y_state=0):
        """Create a new node at x, y"""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        if self.x != 0:
            self.x_state = 1
        else:
            self.x_state = x_state

        if self.y != 0:
            self.y_state = 1
        else:
            self.y_state = y_state

    # some other dunder methods here

    def set_value(self, attr, value):
        if self.[attr]_state == 0:
            self.[attr] = value
            self.[attr]_state = 1
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError
```

The method checks the appropriate 'state' variable and then assigns the x or y variable to the value given by the user if the 'state' is 0, and then gives the 'state' a value of 1, thereby rendering future value assignments useless.

The confusion I have is with dynamically referencing the attributes.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Why are you allowing these objects to be in a half-initialized state, anyway? Why not require `x` and `y` in the constructor?

Comment: Sound like an good application for a `property`.

Comment: You should use `None` to indicate, value not set.

Comment: @user2357112 I hadn't thought that through fully, having read your comment and thought about it I'll change the code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1 (old, backwards compatible style)

Sounds like you would want a namedtuple (or to subclass it). Without anything more specific, it's unclear what would be reasons not to use it.

```
In [7]: from collections import namedtuple
point = namedtuple("Point", ["x", "y"])

In [8]: point
Out[8]: __main__.Point

In [9]: point(1, 2)
Out[9]: Point(x=1, y=2)

In [10]: p = point(1, 2)

In [11]: p.x = 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-4e1ffb2a7978> in <module>()
----> 1 p.x = 1

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Tuples are awesome for this as they are efficient and the "pythonic" way to get immutability.

#### Option 2 (if you care about Python 3.7+)

If you're on the latest version of Python (3.7+), you could do this:

```
In [1]: from dataclasses import dataclass
   ...: 

In [2]: @dataclass(frozen=True)
   ...: class Point():
   ...:     x: int
   ...:     y: int
   ...: 
   ...:     

In [3]: point = Point(x=1, y=2)

In [4]: point
Out[4]: Point(x=1, y=2)

In [5]: point.x = 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FrozenInstanceError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7f9ef2714879> in <module>()
----> 1 point.x = 1

<string> in __setattr__(self, name, value)

FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'x'
```

The cool part here is that it easy to add some functions to extend your `Point`.

#### Option 3 (for shits and giggles)

`setattr` is indeed quite a difficult way to use for your case. Here's an implementation for fun, but this is not recommended code (hacky, and probably there are some edge cases):

```
class Node():

    def __init__(self, x, y):        
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.frozen = True

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if getattr(self, "frozen", False):
            raise ValueError("Cannot change value")
        self.__dict__[key] = value
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, I came across namedtuple in my research but the implementation made it seem somewhat complicated/unwieldy. Since you answered with this so quickly I'm assuming it's the obvious thing to do. I'm relatively new to Python so I wasn't sure what other options there were.

Comment: @Jlanger I added some fun example how you could still use setattr in this case, but again, not recommended :) Good luck with python!

Comment: thanks so much for the extra code and explanation, it's always nice to be shown other things I wasn't aware of. I've learnt more than I thought I would :)